# Unable to automate the Popup in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, popupwindow

i am unable to identify the web elements when a pop up is displayed on clicking  "select your family members" in the below website, i am not sure how to automate this ?
I have tried using Switch window and alert windows.
http://health.policybazaar.com/?utm_content=home_v3

Comment: Show us your code and what / how you actually tried. In this form I nearly flagged this as spam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to switch any window , Use following code

```
    driver.get("http://health.policybazaar.com/?utm_content=home_v3");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
    driver.findElement(By.id("input_6")).click();
```

**Updated :**

```
    WebDriverWait wait =new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='prequote-member-left-section']/md-checkbox[@name='checkboxSelf']/div[1]")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='prequote-member-left-section']/md-checkbox[@name='checkboxSelf']/div[1]")).click();
```

Note : Use `ExplicitWait` to make element visible on next popup and then click

Comment: Once you click on the "Select your Family Member ", you get a pop up to add numbers,i am not able to select the fields inside the popup.

Comment: Which values you want to select ?

Comment: i have tried for every fields but nothing is getting selected inside the pop up

Comment: See the updated code, You need to put some effort to analyze the fact and then do scripting